# Redirect bash output to file within the bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to process multiple videos in a folder and produce results through redirecting their outputs to a text file. When I do this inside the bash script, it doesn't work and doesn't redirect and instead shows on screen. What should I change? How to fix it?

```
for f in *.mp4
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
  python myscript.py $f &> ../log-$f.txt 
done
```

Comment: Remove the & before >. By default it should send the stdout to a file. Another option is `tee`.. `python myscript.py $f | tee ../log-$f.txt`

Comment: But I also need the stderr to be output.

Comment: Use 2>&1, which redirects 2 (stderr) to 1 (stdout), and finally tee will send everything to the file. Something like `python myscript.py "$f" 2>&1 | tee ../log-"$f".txt`. You can replace `| tee` with `>` if you want to. My advice is to try both and see the difference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
python myscript.py $f &> ../log-$f.txt
```

to this:

```
python myscript.py "$f" &> ../log-"$f".txt
```

I didn't check it but it should work, unless you'll have to specify absolute path,
but it's just a guess.