# bash script: Trying to redirect output to a new file created in the last day & 0 bytes in size

Tags: bash

I've been working on a script which takes the output of the yum-cron command & redirects it to a new file. This part is working. However, if there's no new updates & no errors an empty file is created. I decided to try to get the script to write a simple "no new updates" message to the most recently created file.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Only run if this flag is set. The flag is created by the yum-cron init
# script when the service is started -- this allows one to use chkconfig and
# the standard "service stop|start" commands to enable or disable the yum-cron.
if [[ ! -f /var/lock/subsys/yum-cron ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

# Action!
/usr/sbin/yum-cron 2>&1 >> /var/log/yum-cron/yumCronUpdate-"$(date +"%F %T")"
# sleep in case yum-cron actually finds something to do?? Unsure if necessary??
sleep 30s

value=$(find /var/log/yum-cron/ -mtime -1 -size 0 -type f -iname "yumCronUpdate-2022*") | echo "Updates checked, no updates found on $(date + "%F +%T")" >> "$value"
```

I know that the script works up through line 12. In this form I get the error "line 13: No such file or directory." If I run line 13 from the terminal the message is appended to the most recent "yumCornUpdate" file - so it seems to actually work. My guess is that the $value variable isn't getting set as `echo "$value"` doesn't produce an output after the script has run.

If I modify the code to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Only run if this flag is set. The flag is created by the yum-cron init
# script when the service is started -- this allows one to use chkconfig and
# the standard "service stop|start" commands to enable or disable the yum-cron.
if [[ ! -f /var/lock/subsys/yum-cron ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

# Action!
exec /usr/sbin/yum-cron 2>&1 >> /var/log/yum-cron/yumCronUpdate-"$(date +"%F %T")"
# sleep in case yum-cron actually finds something to do?? Unsure if necessary??
sleep 30s

echo "Updates checked, no updates found on $(date + "%F +%T")" >> $(find /var/log/yum-cron/ -mtime -1 -size 0 -type f -iname "yumCronUpdate-2022*")
```

I get the error "line 13: $(find /var/log/yum-cron/ -mtime -1 -size 0 -type f -iname "yumCronUpdate-2022*"): ambiguous redirect

I'm not skilled at bash scripting, this is my first time (I'm used to PowerShell on Windows). I looked around at these topics as well:

[Redirect bash output to file within the bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059917/redirect-bash-output-to-file-within-the-bash-script)

[Getting an "ambiguous redirect" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error)

[How do I redirect output to a variable in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559076/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-a-variable-in-shell)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `find /var/log/yum-cron/ -mtime -1 -size 0 -type f -iname "yumCronUpdate-2022*"` <- are you sure this command always returns a single file? If you're creating files daily, it's quite possible yesterday's file will show up too?

Comment: The files are created weekly, so it should only find 1 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is creating a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html).

```
value=$(find /var/log/yum-cron/ -mtime -1 -size 0 -type f -iname "yumCronUpdate-2022*") | \
echo "Updates checked, no updates found on $(date + "%F +%T")" >> "$value"
```

Basically:

1. The commands on the lefthand and righthand side get spawned in their own subshells. This is why you get no output from `echo "$value"` afterwards, the contents of the subshell are not visible from the parent process.
2. The output of the lefthand side is connected to the input of the righthand side...except that `value=$( command )` doesn't output anything, and even if it did `echo` doesn't read from its standard input so that output wouldn't be used at all.

Rather than trying to capture the file in a variable and reuse it, `find -exec` can detect the files and print things into them for you at the same time.

```
find /var/log/yum-cron/ -mtime -1 -size 0 -type f -iname "yumCronUpdate-2022*" \
-exec /bin/bash -c 'echo "Updates checked, no updates found on $1" >> "$2"' \
_ "$(date  +"%F %T")" {} \;
```

For each file matching the criteria, this command spawns a small bash script that prints your message and the current date to the matched file.

Comment: That did it, I appreciate your explanation of the commands as well!